# Does not conform to protocol Decodabel and Encodable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my approach? the error is

- Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
- Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

I have tried to replace the null string for Var id, pushId and avatarLink with String.self but no avail either.

Please help

> ```
> struct User: Codable, Equatable{
>     
>     var id = ""
>     var username = String.self
>     var email = String.self
>     var pushId = ""
>     var avatarLink = ""
>     var status = String.self
>
>     static var currentId: String {
>         return Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
>     }
>     
>     static var currentUser: User? {
>         if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
>             if let dicctionary = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: kCURRENTUSER) {
>                 
>                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
>                 do {
>                     let userObject = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: dicctionary)
>                     return userObject
>                 } catch {
>                     print("Error decoding user from user defaults ", error.localizedDescription)
>                 }
>                 
>             }
>         }
>         
>         return nil
>     }
>     
>     static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
>         lhs.id == rhs.id
>     }
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: Check the documentation of Encodable and Decodable for required methods than need to be implemented.

Comment: The properties id, pushId and avatarLink are all strings which themselves are codable but username, email and status are String.type (not strings) and that is not codable.

Answer (score 6):

When you write `var username = String.self`, the type of the `username` property will be not `String`, but `String.Type`. Basically, it holds not a string, but a type. A type itself is not encodable or decodable, and because of that the whole struct can't be implicitly codable.

If you want `username`, `email` and `status` to contain strings, but not types, but don't want them to have a default value of an empty string (like `id` or `pushId`), just declare them as follows: `var username: String`.

That will enable Swift compiler to synthesize the `Codable` conformance for you.